# 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument

Tags: c#

When I try to debug it gives two errors:

> Error 1   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value'
>   and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missi`enter code here`ng a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  28  44  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error 2   'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value'
>   and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Home\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  29  40  WindowsFormsApplication1

```
static string connection = @"Data Source=Amaya\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
    double driverCharge;
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate = dtp_rentedDate.Value;
        DateTime endDate = dtp_returnedDate.Value;
        int startKm = int.Parse(txtstart_Km.Text);
        int endKm = int.Parse(txtend_Km.Text);
        string Veh_ID = cmb_VID.SelectedValue.ToString();

        double basicCharge = 0.0;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
```

{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillComboBox();
        }

```
    static string connection = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-RFLE48T\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ayubo_Drive;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
    double driverCharge;
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate = startDate.Value;
        DateTime endDate = endDate.Value;
        int startKm = int.Parse(txtstart_Km.Text);
        int endKm = int.Parse(txtend_Km.Text);
        string Veh_ID = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        double basicCharge = 0.0;


        if (rbRent.Checked)
        {
            basicCharge = rentcalculation(Veh_ID, startDate, endDate, false);
        }
        else if (rbRentW_driver.Checked)
        {
            basicCharge = rentcalculation(Veh_ID, startDate, endDate, true);
        }


        txt_basic.Text = String.Format("{0:.00}", basicCharge);

    }

    private void FillComboBox()
    {

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select V_ID from Vehicle_Type", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "V_ID";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "V_ID";

    }



    public double rentcalculation(string Veh_ID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, bool withDriver)
    {
        double rent = 0.0;
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Vehicle_Type  WHERE V_ID=@001", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@001", Veh_ID);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (r.Read())
            {
                double daycharge = double.Parse(r["V_dayRent"].ToString());
                double weekcharge = double.Parse(r["v_weekRent"].ToString());
                double monthlycharge = double.Parse(r["v_monthlyRent"].ToString());
                driverCharge = double.Parse(r["v_driverCharge"].ToString());
                TimeSpan ts = endDate.Date - startDate.Date;
                int total_Days = ts.Days + 1;
                int Days = total_Days;
                int month = (int)Days / 30;
                Days = Days % 30;
                int weekCount = (int)Days / 7;
                Days = Days % 7;

                rent = month * monthlycharge + weekCount * weekcharge + Days * daycharge;

                if (withDriver)
                {
                    driverCharge = total_Days * driverCharge;
                    txt_driver.Text = driverCharge.ToString();

                    double totCharge = rent + driverCharge;
                    txt_total.Text = totCharge.ToString();
                }

                else
                {
                    txt_driver.Text = "0.0";
                    txt_total.Text = rent.ToString();  
                }


            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {

                con.Close();
        }
        return rent;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It seems `dtp_rentedDate` is a `DateTime` rather than (guessing) a `DateTimePicker` control as the variable name suggests. In that case, omit `.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

What is data type of dtp_rentedDate object ? It seems it is System.DateTime which really does not contain "Value" property, as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2).
I think that you wanted to use some other variable, which is visual control which serves for input of datetime value on GUI. Please take a better look at your code, and see how that control is named. And then replace dtp_rentedDate with that string.

Comment: that worked but now i got another error 
"Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments
"Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' to 'System.Data.DataTable'